# how do you open a jquery ui dialog window in parent/opener window?

Tags: jquery-ui, backbone.js, popup, underscore.js, jquery-ui-dialog

I am trying to get a jquery ui dialog to open in a parent window from a child window.  In other words, as the child can only have the dialog popup only with in its window's constraints,  I would like to be able to use the contents of the dialog's popup in the constraints of the parent window.

I was trying to use a window.opener to tie in a link, but wasn't having much luck.

Here's the code that opens the window from a Backbone View HTML page:

```
popoutWindow = window.open("campaign/genericPopout.aspx", "search", "width=800, height=600, toolbar=0, status=0, menubar=0, scrollbars=1, resizable=1", true);
```

inside the genericPopout.apsx's call to a file that builds, with Backbone View, with this command,

```
new popupSearchView();
```

it calls the following Backbone View:

```
var popupSearchView = Backbone.View.extend({
    events: {
        "click #closeBtn" : "closePopupSerachView"
    },

    initialize: function() {
        this.template = _.template("<div id='searchPopupView'>" +
                                       "<div style='width: 100%; text-align: center;'>Hello World</div>" +
                                       "<div style='text-align: center;'><input type='button' id='closeBtn' value='Close' /></div>" +
                                   "</div>"
                                  );
        this.render();
    },

    render: function () {
        formString = this.template();
        $(formString).dialog({
            autoOpen: true,
            height:460,
            width: 350,
            title: "Search",
            modal: false
        })

        return this;
    },

    closePopupSearchView: function () {
        $(this).dialog("close");
    }
});
```

It opens the popup dialog fine within the newly opened window, but it doesn't seem to work.  In the parent window HTML, I have a div devoted to this dialog:

```
<div id="popupSearchViewDiv"></div>
```

and I tried setting the Backbone el to this div by this:

```
el: $("popupSearchViewDiv", window.opener.document)
```

yet this does not seem to work.  Any thoughts on how I can accomplish this?

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a way to do this.  I'm not sure how efficient it is, but it may be the only way.

In the opener window, I placed the code jquery-ui dialog:

```
function openSearchViewPopup() {
    $("#popupSearchViewDiv").dialog({
        autoOpen: true,
        height:460,
        width: 350,
        title: "Search",
        modal: false
}
```

With a predefined DIV in the index.aspx of:

```
 <div id="popupSearchViewDiv"></div>
```

From the window opened from the index.aspx that holds the above function code, I call the function like this:

```
render: function () {
    var htmlToWrite = this.template();
    $(window.opener.docuemnt.getElementById("popupSearchViewDiv").append(htmlToWrite);

    $window.opener.openSearchViewPopup();
}
```

This seems to allow the jquery-ui dialog popup to open in the window.opener window and to be used there.